# Avoid downloadable files in Python Urlopen

Tags: python, urllib

I am building a web crawler using python. But the `urlopen(url)` download the files in the page. I just want to read the html, and skip if the url points to a downloadable file.

I have tried using timeouts

```
urlopen(url, timeout = 5).read()
```

so that large files can be avoided, but this doesn't seem to work.

I also thought to make a list of common file extensions, and skip the url whenever the url ends with the extension.

```
flag = False
extensions = ['.zip', '.mp3',....]
for extension in extensions:
    if url.endswith(extension):
        flag = True
        continue
if not flag:
    x = urlopen(url).read()
```

But this method will not be very efficient I suppose.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Content-Type` HTTP header to find out if it's HTML or something else:

```
x= urlopen(url)
if 'text/html' in x.headers.get('Content-Type'):
    x= x.read()
```

Comment: I think he wants before opening url?

Comment: You can't directly, but you can do a `HEAD` request to get just the headers, then examine them to determine whether you want to do a full `GET`.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by [python requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

```
In [8]: import requests

In [9]: h = requests.head("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771237/avoid-downloadable-files-in-python-urlopen")

In [10]: if "text/html" in h.headers["content-type"]:
   ....:     content = requests.get("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771237/avoid-downloadable-files-in-python-urlopen").text
   ....:
```

Answer (score 0):

To narrow the amount of file content to check, check `retcode` before checking file content.

```
doc = urllib.urlopen(url, timeout=5)
if doc and doc.getCode() == 200 and doc.headers.get('Content-Type').startswith("text/html"):
    x = doc.read()
```